# Writing with different fonts in pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm trying to use this font I grabbed from the internet in an opening screen in pygame. Here's the function I used, but no matter what I used as the font name it doesn't change what appears. After using `pygame.font.SysFont` it stopped giving not found error. All I want is to use this other font

```
def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, WHITE)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def message_display(text):
    largeText = pygame.font.SysFont('Minecraftia.ttf',115)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((HEIGHT/2),(WIDTH/2))
    screen.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)
```

Comment: Could you show us the declaration of your font?

Comment: `message_display("Test")`

Comment: From [pygame documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html?highlight=font#module-pygame.font) `pygame.font.SysFont` = **create a Font object from the system fonts**. Did you install `'Minecraftia.ttf'` using your OS tools?

Comment: Ahh,, no. I just hit install this explains it thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [`freetype`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/freetype.html#pygame.freetype.Font) module instead of the [`font`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html) module. It's a replacement for `font` and better in every way.

Both modules have two classes for representing fonts:

`SysFont`: create a Font object from the system fonts

`Font`: create a new Font instance from a supported font file.

In your case, since you want to load a font from a font file instead of using a system font, use the `Font` class instead of `SysFont`.